# How to get rid of downcast in this case?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I broke my head over this already. So here is the situation. I have two types of documents with similar properties. High-level (base-level) properties (Name, Date) are required in one place, "Rows" are required to create specific document to send to another system. How it is implemented now:

Data classes:

```
    public abstract class BaseDocument
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class BaseDocument<TRowType> : BaseDocument
    {
        public abstract List<TRowType> Rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class DocumentTypeOne : BaseDocument<RowTypeOne>
    {
        public override List<RowTypeOne> Rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class DocumentTypeTwo : BaseDocument<RowTypeTwo>
    {
        public override List<RowTypeTwo> Rows { get; set; }
    }


    public class RowTypeOne
    {
        public int Cost { get; set; }
    }

    public class RowTypeTwo
    {
        public int Change { get; set; }
    }
```

ProcessorClass:

```
    public class DocumentsProcessor
    {
        public void ProcessDocument(BaseDocument doc)
        {
            switch (doc)
            {
                case DocumentTypeOne t1:
                    ProcessDocumentTypeOne((DocumentTypeOne)doc);
                    break;
                case DocumentTypeTwo t2:
                    ProcessDocumentsTypeTwo((DocumentTypeTwo)doc);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Unhandled type {nameof(doc)}");
            }
        }

        public void ProcessDocumentTypeOne(DocumentTypeOne docOne)
        {
            // specific actions
        }

        public void ProcessDocumentsTypeTwo(DocumentTypeTwo docTwo)
        {
            // other specific actions
        }
    }
```

I know that downcasting is not good. But I have no ideas how to change it.
I can make base class with generic parameter but then I'll lost ability to work with only base-level properties. And this will require to rewrite class that return List.
What's the way to solve it? And is it needed to be solved?

Comment: What do want to get?

Comment: Could you please explain, what is the problem with your code?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It's about downcasting. I think it looks bad like it has bad smell. But it works and I see no other way to make it significantly better.

Comment: @Backs I think something without downcasting. But I dont see how.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use interfaces.

```
public interface IBaseDocument
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public interface IDocumentWithRows<T>
{
    List<T> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentTypeOne: IBaseDocument, IDocumentWithRows<RowTypeOne>
{
    string IBaseDocument.Name { get; set; }
    DateTime IBaseDocument.Date { get; set; }
    List<RowTypeOne> IDocumentWithRows<RowTypeOne>.Rows { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentProcessor
{
    public void ProcessDocument(IBaseDocument doc)
    {
        switch (doc)
        {
            case DocumentTypeOne docTypeOne:
                ProcessDocumentTypeOne(docTypeOne);
                break;
            case DocumentTypeTwo docTypeTwo:
                ProcessDocumentTypeTwo(docTypeTwo);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```